# How to use AVG() function after converting a substring to a numeric format?

Tags: sql, oracle, average, substr

In my example there are two columns like: "ID" (NUMBER) and "NUMBER_COUNT" (VARCHAR2) which currently look like:

```
ID: 1234567 -> NUMBER_COUNT = ':123:999:100:500:502:' 
ID: 1111111 -> NUMBER_COUNT = ':444:543:100:664:404:'
```

I want to get the AVG() of NUMBER_COUNT grouped by ID, therefore the output should look like:

```
ID          numbers_avg
1234567     444.8
1111111     431
```

I already tried this:

```
      select 
        e.ID, 
        AVG(to_number(substr(e.NUMBER_COUNT, instr(e.NUMBER_COUNT, ':', 1, level) + 1, 
            instr(e.NUMBER_COUNT, ':', 1, level + 1) - instr(e.NUMBER_COUNT, ':', 1,
            level) - 1),'99999999D99999')) as numbers_avg
      from TABLE e
      connect by level <= length(e.NUMBER_COUNT) - length(replace(e.NUMBER_COUNT, ':')) - 1
      group by e.ID;
```

The statement can be executed. Unfortunately ORACLE neither displays any result, nor error.

Can someone provide help on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be storing the data this way. Normalizing the structure will be the best solution.

For now, you can use `regexp_substr` and also, fix you `connect by` to not create loops using `sys_guid()`.

```
select
  id,
  avg(regexp_substr(number_count, '\d+', 1, level))
from your_table
connect by level <= regexp_count(number_count, ':')
and prior id = id
and prior sys_guid() is not null
group by id;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/IJLLBY68224)

Answer (score 0):

I have the sense that you were somehow trying to explode the colon separated string in the `NUMBER_COUNT` column, and then aggregate the numbers using `GROUP BY`.  I think the easiest approach here might be to just use `SUBSTR()` and take the average of the 5 numbers, casting each number as needed.

```
SELECT ID, (CAST(SUBSTR(NUMBER_COUNT, 2, 3) AS NUMBER) +
            CAST(SUBSTR(NUMBER_COUNT, 6, 3) AS NUMBER) +
            CAST(SUBSTR(NUMBER_COUNT, 10, 3) AS NUMBER) +
            CAST(SUBSTR(NUMBER_COUNT, 14, 3) AS NUMBER) +
            CAST(SUBSTR(NUMBER_COUNT, 18, 3) AS NUMBER)) / 5 AS numbers_avg
FROM yourTable
```

Note that I would expect this approach to be **faster** than using `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`, which was suggested by others.  I don't see the need for regex here, because Oracle's base string functions have the problem covered.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester